# How to change operator in schema.xml and configure site for AND search

Tags: search

I am using Solr search with drupal.Its working fine on my site but the problem is
i needed the search to be a specific to the searched content.
If i searched for "assembly and key",the search result showing all results which is having the world assembly and key also.

But I needed the result like wherever this particular word is found not the separate.
when i search for "assembly and key" it is giving me around 55 results and when i am searching "assembly+and+key", it is giving only 1 result which is i want.
So please let me know how to do it.

I have tried to change solr/conf/schema.xml for AND operator also tried to add code in apachesolr module file for changing the mm parameter but it doesn't work.

Comment: Finally i didnt found any good solution.So i have done it through drupal coding.
i have added OP='AND' in Solr_Base_Query.php also changed mm=100% and op=AND.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to edit the Solr_Base_Query.php file just add the following line of the code in your module

```
function modulename_apachesolr_query_prepare($query){
$query -> addParam('q.op', 'OR');
```

}

Comment: thanks for the answer i already added it which is working fine now.